# PHP MySql display returned content without html tags being stripped

Tags: php, mysql, html, tags, strip

I have a column in SQL 'Text' datatype and inside I have content within html tag, eg

somecontent:

- one
- two

... I want the mysql query to echo out the databases contents without stripping the html tags (its possible this is done by php for security reasons or?) so that the html code will render if you get me? At the moment it just lumps out a paragraph which looks aweful! It should be noted security is not much of a concern as this is a project and not going to be exposed publicly

Cheers folks

Nick

Comment: Accroding to your description the awful paragraph is the content of your SQL result. Everything seems to be fine. ... Are you missing styling by CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL wouldn't strip tags from text - it couldn't care less what the text is. PHP also wouldn't strip tags, unless somewhere in your code you do a `strip_tags()` or equivalent.

If you want to force the browser to display the tags in the retrieved data, you can run the string through [`htmlspecialchars()][1]`, which converts html metacharacters (`<`, `>`, `"`, `&`, etc...) to their character entity equivalents (`&lt;`, `&gt;`, etc...).

Or you can force the entire page to be rendered as plain text by doing

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

Comment: Thanks for that, its working, actually think the problem was to do with older data in the column without tags, doh, cheers man :)

Answer (score 1):

Database content isn't stripped by PHP unless you explicitly tell it to.
Are you sure your tags haven't been stripped before they were inserted?

Alternatively try `stripslashes();`

Answer (score 0):

Use htmlspecialchars_decode() function. Its works fine for me...

Use guideline

Your Text with code

```
<?php

$text = " 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
     Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.
</body>
</html> ";

OR

$text = $row['columnname'];  // Here define your database table column name.

echo htmlspecialchars_decode($text);
```

?>

Output:

Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

Ex:

```
<?=htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlspecialchars('I <b>love</b> you'))?>
```

Your browser will output: 
I **love** you

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow snippet:

```
echo(strip_tags($your_string));
```

copied.